# Can anyone share in-depth Details information about Method Access Modifier?

Tags: c#

I have some doubt about method access modifier and I share my working example there is some real-time doubt so can anybody have an idea please share your information.

when inherit a super class to sub-class why should all method showing same I created instance it showing 3 methods only(public, internal, protected internal), if I use this application Bin to another application with inheritance(public, protected, protected internal) methods only showing, if I create instance(public) method only showing

**class 1:**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string str1()
        {
            return "Ethiraj";
        }

        protected string str2()
        {
            return "Ethiraj";
        }

        internal string str3()
        {
            return "Ethiraj";
        }

        protected internal string str4()
        {
            return "Ethiraj";
        }

        private string str5()
        {
            return "Ethiraj";
        }

        public virtual void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sealed method");
        }
    }
}
```

same application but a different class with the same namespace.

**class 2**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Testing2 : Test
    {
        public void str()
        {
            Test obj = new Test();
            obj.str1();
            obj.str3();
            obj.str4();

            str1();
            str2();
            str3();
            str4();
        }
    }
}
```

new application with above application exe was refereed

**new app class:**

```
using ClassLibrary1;
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Program : Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test obj = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine(obj.str1());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void ethi()
        {
            str1();
            str2();
            str4();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the use of method access modifier?

Comment: Reading and understanding the documentation is a very important skill for a developer. Please refer to [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) on Microsoft docs and if you still have thins you need clarification on, then post a question.

Comment: good, i read fully your link and i got it, my question is why it is restrict by instance creation allowed in inheritance

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: same method access modifier open in inheritance but not in instance then what it is scope of access modifier, i understood the theory, why should it allow other way that is my thinking

Comment: the access modifier role is restrict the access correct but it is restrict in instance allowed in inheritance, that is my question

Comment: Still not clear, sorry. If you are talking about a specific access modifier, what is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of access modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895101/what-is-the-purpose-of-access-modifiers)

Comment: if we use super class exe to new application with instance it will allow only public method correct

Comment: as same time it allow to use same method to call and override by inheritance, why it restrict in class object instance creation, why it allow in inheritance

Comment: if someone created exe with public internal, protected internal, i cannot access by instance, but i can access by inheritance that is possible, why there is allowing and blocking

Comment: I don't follow. [You can't change the access modifier by inheritance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383620/cannot-change-access-modifiers-when-overriding-public-inherited-member/50383733#50383733).

Comment: okay that is not possible i agree Zohar peled, my question is not that

Comment: So are you asking specifically about `protected internal` (there is no such thing as `public internal`, everything that's `public` already can be accessed from within the same assembly, so adding `internal` to `public` is redundant.

Comment: same assembly okay even there is public, internal, protect internal only access by instance, but we can access all method by inheritance except private

Comment: my question simple why it is allowed in inheritance rather than instance, if inheritance means user easy to access method, recreate same method name, even if there was virtual easy to override

Comment: Ok - `protected internal` is a mix of both `protected` and `internal` - meaning the class member (method, field, property, event or indexer) can be accessed either by other classes in the same assembly (that's the `internal` part) or by classes inheriting the class where the `protected internal` member is declared (even if they belong to a different assembly).